# Как выбрать, что хранить в БД?

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Добрый день, не знаю как поступить, что хранить в базе данных?
Объясняю:
База данных создается для работы с заказами. Заказы вводятся в программе. На основе заказов создаются платежные документы, содержащие конкретные услуги - например добавляют заказ "Добавить заказ на перевод, языки Английский, Русский, Перевод нотариально заверить.", при этом добавление заказа реализуется заполнением формы "заказ на перевод", содержащей input'ы для указания языков, и чекбокс для указания будет заверение или не будет. На основе этих данных создаются две услуги - "перевод с европейских(или западных) языков, нотариальное заверение перевода.".
Так вот, что должно храниться в базе данных?

1. информационные поля заказа (два языка и булево значение "есть заверение или нет"). На основе этих данных всегда можно автоматически составить эти две конкретные услуги.
2. должны хранится именно услуги. Потому что наверное полезно иметь возможность делать выборки по разным типам услуг, да и в конце концов именно услуги попадают потом в документы.
   Но по таким услугам не получится восстановить полную входную информацию о заказе, например те же языки (так как в услуге указывается только европейские они или западные), а значит придется хранить дополнительные сведения и заказа.
3. из пункта 2) вытекает этот пункт - и то и то. И заказ в виде набора полей. И ассоциированный с ним набор услуг в отдельной таблице. Но набор услуг можно получить динамически из данных заказов, не будет ли это дублированием?

Какой вариант выбрать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть строгий набор услуг:

Таблица заказов(orders):

```
id | date | итд..
```

Таблица услуг(services):

```
id | order_id | service_type_id
```

Таблица типов услуг(service_types):

```
id | name
```

Таблица свойств(options):

```
id  |   service_id  |   option_type_id
1   |   2           |   1
2   |   4           |   4
3   |   6           |   5
```

Таблица типов опций(option_types):

```
id  |   name
1   |   Английский  
2   |   Немецкий    
3   |   Ускоренный курс 
4   |   Другой курс
5   |   Сделать быстро
6   |   Вредный заказчик
```

В таком варианте все данные о заказе у вас будут храниться в числовом виде, что поможет вам в будущем избежать проблем. Естественно, что виды услуг и языки нужно предварительно заполнить в базу. И текстовые инпуты заменить на селекты с их выбором.

Comment: Спасибо, огромное!

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, если разные услуги имеют разные поля, то для каждого типа услуги создают отдельную таблицу, связанную с таблицей заказов по внешнему ключу?

Comment: mJeevas, а что, если для разных типов услуг нужно хранить разные данные, тогда как модифицировать ваш пример?
Если для каждого вида услуги хранить свою таблицу услуг это вида (firstType_services, secondType_services), то при добавлении в систему нового вида услуги придется добавлять такую таблицу, но как не поломать запрос, собирающий все услуги входящие в заказ (orders)?

Comment: Если расширять свойства больше, чем просто разделение на языки, то можно переделать таблицы языков под все свойства. Зависит от того, какой у вас проект, что там может быть и что не быть. И уже отталкиваясь от этого думать над структурой базы. Без этих нюансов я вам не смогу помочь в этом вопросе.

Comment: Смотрите, структура таблиц наверняка будет очень похожей на ту, что Вы показали. Сейчас в таблице "languages" хранятся вся языки, связанные с услугой в таблице "services". Формируя заказ, мы смотрим, какие услуги в него входят, и для каждой услуги ищем языки в этой таблице. 
А что если не все услуги - перевод? Есть еще вид услуги - услуга чтения курса, у которой нет никаких языков, но есть название курса. Получается, что нам нужна таблица Курсы(id, service_id, course_name). Теперь, формируя заказ, мы пробегаемся по услугам, и если это услуга перевода - то ищем языки, а если курс - название

Comment: это хороший подход? При добавление нового типа услуги, будем добавлять таблицу для хранения данных о ней, и модифицировать запрос формирования заказа, чтобы он, когда встречал тип этой услуги в своих услугах лез в нужную таблицу?
Или я путаю и натыкаюсь на подводные камни?

Comment: При таком варианте, если вдруг нужно будет потом добавить новое свойство, вам придется добавлять новые таблицы, редактировать код сайта. Лучше переименуйте таблицы language в options и кладите все опции в одну эту таблицу. Если нужно логически разделять опции, то добавьте еще таблицу в описанием типов опций и связывайте также по id

Comment: Получится одна таблица с большим кол-вом столбцов? В ней будут заполнены только те свойства, которые актуальны для данного вида услуги. А пр добалении нового вида услуги, ее свойства можно будет дописать в конец этой таблицы и запрос на формирование заказа для остальных услуг не поменяется? 
Я никогда так не делал, спасибо большое, что посоветовали. Подтвердите только, пожалуйста, что я все правильно понял!

Comment: Две таблицы: переименованные languages и language_types. В languages лежат id типа из language_types и id услуги. В language_types лежат вперемешку все свойства, что у вас есть в текстовом виде.

Comment: В текстовом виде - Вы имеете ввиду сереализованые в одну строку?

Comment: Обновил ответ. Смотрите последние 2 талицы

Answer (score 0):

Всегда очень внимательно подумайте когда вы хотите сделать нечто вычисляемым значением. Часто меняются правила по которым нужно вычислять, но старые вычисленные величины при этом должны оставатся неизменными.

Кроме того я вижу даже с точки зрения бизнеса 2 различные сущности "Заказ" и "Услуга" которые вполне себе могу существовать отдельно. Например в заказ впоследствии будет добавлятся автоматом третья услуга, получается в старых заказах у вас возникнут фантомные третьи услуги которых не было.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!
Значит в таких вещах лучше не боятся некоторого дублирования.
Подскажите, если принять разделение на две сущности, как Вы сказали, "Заказ" и "Услуга", то что в программе можно создавать только заказ содержащий конкретные две услуги, и нельзя совместить произвольные услуги, это не отразится тут?

Comment: да, я понял, как раз это Вы и описали, когда говорили про фантомные услуги.